# Express polynomial coefficients as terms of a matrix determinant or function of matrix determinants

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, polynomials, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

The impulse-response function $h\left(u\right)_1$ of a linear system where the linear system has a parameter $k_i$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
h\left(u\right)_1 = \frac{1}{k_1}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_1}
\end{equation}

if the output from this system is immediately fed into another linear system with parameter $k_2$, then the resulting impulse response is given by:

\begin{equation}
h\left(u\right)_2 = \frac{1}{k_1-k_2}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2-k_1}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_2}
\end{equation}

and if this is passed through a third linear filter with parameter $k_3$...

\begin{equation}
h\left(u\right)_3 = \frac{k_1}{\left(k_1-k_2\right)\left(k_1-k_3\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_1} + \frac{k_2}{\left(k_2-k_1\right)\left(k_2-k_3\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_2} + \frac{k_3}{\left(k_3-k_1\right)\left(k_3-k_2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_3}
\end{equation}

such that the general form of this equation becomes:

\begin{equation}
h\left(u\right)_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\{\frac{k_i^{n-2}\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_i}}{\prod_{j=1}^n\left(k_i-k_j\right)}\right\} \quad \mbox{for} \quad j \neq i
\end{equation}

Similarly, the autocovariance of the output from a cascade of linear systems, assuming a white noise input, can be expressed in a similar way as:

\begin{align}
 \gamma_{yy}\left(\tau\right)_1 =&\,\, \frac{1}{2k_1}\\
 \gamma_{yy}\left(\tau\right)_2 =&\,\, \frac{k_1}{2\left(k_1^2-k_2^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_1} + \frac{k_2}{2\left(k_2^2-k_1^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_2}\\
 \gamma_{yy}\left(\tau\right)_3 =&\,\, \frac{k_1^3}{2\left(k_1^2-k_2^2\right)\left(k_1^2-k_3^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_1} + \frac{k_2^3}{2\left(k_2^2-k_1^2\right)\left(k_2^2-k_3^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_2} + \frac{k_3^3}{2\left(k_3^2-k_1^2\right)\left(k_3^2-k_2^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_3}\\
 \gamma_{yy}\left(\tau\right)_4 =&\,\, \frac{k_1^5}{2\left(k_1^2-k_2^2\right)\left(k_1^2-k_3^2\right)\left(k_1^2-k_4^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_1} + \frac{k_2^5}{2\left(k_2^2-k_1^2\right)\left(k_2^2-k_3^2\right)\left(k_2^2-k_4^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_2}+\\
 &\,\,\frac{k_3^5}{2\left(k_3^2-k_1^2\right)\left(k_3^2-k_2^2\right)\left(k_3^2-k_4^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_3} + \frac{k_4^5}{2\left(k_4^2-k_1^2\right)\left(k_4^2-k_2^2\right)\left(k_4^2-k_3^2\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_4} 
\end{align}

which can be generalised as:

\begin{equation}
 \gamma_{yy}\left(\tau\right)_n = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n\left\{\frac{k_i^{\left(2n-3\right)}\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_i}}{\prod_{j=1,\, j\neq i}^n\left(k_i^2-k_j^2\right)}\right\} \quad \mbox{for} \quad j \neq i 
\end{equation}

My question is this:  can the coefficients of $\mathrm{e}^{-u/k_i}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{-\tau/k_i}$ be expressed as determinants or sub-determinants of a matrix containing functions of the parameters $k_i$?

I am interested in doing this because if it were possible, it would perhaps be a more computationally-efficient way to obtain the impulse-response and covariance functions, because at present I have to write bespoke code to construct them from the solutions above.

Any thoughts gratefully received.